# calculate an ML model object and assign it to a R data.table column

Tags: r, machine-learning, data.table

I would like to assign a trained model object to a data.table column so then I can work with it and assign it as I want. I have the following example data:

```
              category min_price max_price avg_price avg_total_cost max_price_total_cost avg_quantity stores_year upc_sales_year    match
1:     HYGIENE PRODUCT      7.98     21.00  15.44070       21.16016               384.96     5.421875          58            128       1
2:                 TEA      0.60    107.50  11.30844       21.31594               107.50    13.984375          30             64       0
3:        ENDULCORANTS      0.60     28.00  11.72000       30.60000                40.00    14.600000           3              5       1
4: VEGETABLES/FRUITS        6.00     13.50  11.58273       85.67364               234.00    10.363636           8             11       0
5:     AUTO PARTS          29.76     38.88  34.91000       34.91000                38.88     4.500000           4              4       1
6:   CANDY                 10.60     46.00  31.95703       41.04363              2627.64     3.499127         207            573       1
```

and I have the following code:

```
library(randomForest)
library(caret)
library(data.table)

rand.tree.predictions <- function(dfexternal) {
  data <- copy(dfexternal)
  setDT(data)
  train.data <- data[
    match == 1,
    .(min_price, max_price, avg_price, avg_total_cost, max_price_total_cost, avg_quantity, stores_year, upc_sales_year)
    ]
  
  test.data <- data[
    match == 0,
    .(upc_code, min_price, max_price, avg_price, max_price_total_cost, avg_quantity, stores_year, upc_sales_year)
    ]
  
  model <- train(avg_total_cost ~ min_price + max_price + avg_price + max_price_total_cost + avg_quantity + stores_year + upc_sales_year,
                 data = train.data,
                 method = 'rf',
                 trControl = trainControl(method = 'cv', number = 5)
  )
  
  #test.data$avg_total_cost_predicted <- predict(model, newdata = test.data)
  #predict(model, newdata = test.data)
  #result <- predict(model, newdata = test.data)
  return(model)
}
```

where I define a function that trains the model and returns the trained model. However when I run it as follows:

```
reference.prices[, model := rand.tree.predictions(.SD)), by = category]
```

returns the following error:

```
Error in `[.data.table`(reference.prices, , `:=`(model, list(rand.tree.predictions(.SD))),  : 
  Supplied 23 items to be assigned to group 1 of size 64 in column 'model'. The RHS length must either be 1 (single values are ok) or match the LHS length exactly. If you wish to 'recycle' the RHS please use rep() explicitly to make this intent clear to readers of your code.
```

the `model` object is a list but I don't understand the reason it throws that exception.

Comment: try `reference.prices[, model := .(.(rand.tree.predictions(.SD)))), category]`

Comment: @chinsoon12 thank you, it solved the problem and I could perform the predictions. However I was wondering if you could explain me the reasoning of why put the model like ".(.( model))"?